# (F.g., f.p.) groups with exactly $n$ normal subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Dear All!

I tried for several evenings to find an answer to the following basic question and I cannot see what is the answer:

Given an integer $n\geq 3$, does there exist an (infinite) group with exactly $n$ normal subgroups?

If "yes", what about the same questions for finitely generated groups, finitely presented groups?

I guess this must have been done.

Comment: How many subgroups does a finite cyclic group have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $n$ is even, then the answer is "yes". Take the direct product of a simple (infinite) group and ${\mathbb Z}/2^j{\mathbb Z}$. Every normal subgroup either is inside the finite cyclic group or contains the simple group. Total number is twice the number of normal subgroups of the cyclic group.If $n$ is odd, you would need to take a cyclic central extension of a simple group. That is also possible (the simple group can be, say, the Tarski monster, see our paper with Olshanskii and Osin on Lacunary hyperbolic groups in the arXiv).

**Edit.**  If you want f.p. groups, look at the central extensions of the Thompson group $T$ described [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.628&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: The next variation might combine this with the requirement that the group be not residually less than kappa for certain cardinals kappa.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.24

Comment: A simpler 'next' variant would be to ask for a torsion-free example.

Comment: @HW: Such a group can be constructed for $n$ powers of 2 as direct powers of the Burger-Mozes group $G$ (or any other torsion-free simple group). The group $G^n$ has exactly $2^n$ normal subgroups. If $n$ is not a power of 2 one needs to build extensions towers of simple groups. That's not going to be easy. 

Answer (score 3):

In general, $\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}$ has $k+1$ normal subgroups, namely $\mathbb{Z}/2^j\mathbb{Z}$ for $0\leq j\leq k$.  So the answer to your question is "yes."

Comment: Sorry, I meant infinite groups of course!

Comment: Surely Daniel's answer deserves to be accepted?  It answers the question you asked.

Comment: @HW: That's alright; it wasn't the question he intended to ask.  I certainly don't mind.